# How to disable @synthesize in XCode 4.4

Tags: xcode4.4, synthesize

Xcode 4.4 does not need `@synthesize` for outlets. Yet it still generates it when I use the Referencing Outlet connector in Xcode. Is there anyway to tell it not to generate the `@synthesize`? I looked for setting in the project and prefs but could't find anything.

Examples of what it generates in the .m file:

```
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize lastName = _lastName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off the synthesize warnings by clicking on the project name in the Project Navigator on the left then click All Cobined in Build Settings and then search for synthesize. That should be set to No.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question. You asked how to tell Interface Builder not to generate the @synthesize statements. Did you find out how to do that? (Other than upgrading to Xcode 4.5, which no generates them.)

Comment: You're right. Could not find any such behavior,  but under the above setting this is the description:  "Starting in Xcode 4.4, the Apple LLVM Compiler will implicitly synthesize properties that are not
explicitly synthesized using @synthesize.  This warning warns about such implicit behavior, even though the property is still synthesized.  This is essentially a backwards compatability warning, or for those who wish to continue to explicitly use @synthesize."

Comment: Right, I was just hoping there was a way to control Interface Builder's behaviour. I actually want the opposite effect: I was using Xcode 4.5 at home but need to be able to build on 4.3.2 installations (where compiler doesn't support auto-synthesizing). I had to downgrade to 4.4 to get the automatic generation of @synthesize statements back.